# Hide Views with custom module

Tags: views, 7

Hi I would like to create a custom module where I can do extra checks on a view and if those checks are not pass deny access. I'm not sure what hook to implement to achieve this.

Comment: Do you menu or module?

Comment: I'm sorry, custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two Views hooks: [hook_views_api()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) and [hook_views_plugins()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins/7). Have a look at `views_views_plugins()` in Views' `/includes/plugins.inc` file for an example implementation of the plugin hook; specifically, look at the plugins in the `'access'` key.

Beyond that, look at the `views_plugin_access*` files in `/plugins/` for examples of actual implementations.

Comment: I haven't done too much of this so please bear with me. So I create:

Comment: I haven't done too much of this so please bear with me. So I create the hook_views_api() which is essentially the version then I create MODULENAME.views.inc with the views_views_plugin() with the access section that has a handler to my custom plugin? I'm not really sure what to do with the handler? Just return t('Unrestricted'); if validation doesn't pass?

Comment: To be honest I can easily achieve what I want in the tpl file but I know this is not the drupal way and would like to do it correctly.

Comment: Never mind I was able to achieve what I wanted in template.php. Creating a module for this simple task seemed to create extra work that didn't need to be done.